# Instantiate a collection with default value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the below attribute (called `role`) which may contain several `Role`

```
@OneToMany
Collection<Role> role=Arrays.asList(new Role[]{new Role(SystemRole.USER)});
```

The Role is another entity as below:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    SystemRole systemRole;

    public Role(SystemRole role) {
        this.systemRole=role;
    }

}
```

So, the point of this line is to make a default value for `role`:

```
Collection<Role> role=Arrays.asList(new Role[]{new Role(SystemRole.USER)});
```

but it does not work and complain with:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
```

Comment: When asking about an exception thrown by some code, always post the code, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet regardless of the exception, is the initiation of the collection true? I will update my code

Comment: It depends on what you intend to do (and are doing) with the collection. Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: A List created with Arrays.asList cannot have elements added or removed, since it is backed by an array and arrays have a fixed size.  Try wrapping it in `new ArrayList<>(…)`.